# C# перспективные для трудоустройства технологии

Tags: c#

В каком порядке начать изучение web разработку на С# и какие более перспективные для трудоустройства?

Comment: Зависит от вашего представления о языке программирования c#. Если вы начинающий то начните с любой из книг Эндрю Троелсена.

Comment: ну так и посмотрите требования в соответствующих вакансиях, оттуда и узнаете необходимые технологии. Web-разработка очень широкое понятие и одним языком не ограничивается.

Comment: @Евгений на шарпе я работаю уже год ,но только десктоп,вот решил расширить кругозор.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C# сам по себе это только язык и всё. Скорее, если говорят про C# то сразу подразумевают майкрософтовый стек технологий вообще и дотнет в частности.

Если же мы говорим про веб-программирование в целом, по сути, всегда был востребован "full stack developer" -- просто потому что это очень выгодно работодателю -- такой универсальный специалист, не надо думать в какую дырку его засунуть.

Собственно из дотнетового стека сейчас востребовано:

- .NET в целом -- это вообще как работает дотнет, CLR, Base Class Library
- ADO.NET как основа работы с данными
- ASP.NET -- неприоритетно и уже legacy, но ещё много где использется
- Entity Framework -- один из основных ORM из используемых сейчас
- ASP.NET MVC

Но при этом предполагается что дотнетчик ещё и знает другие общие вещи, например, SQL -- в случае дотнета это обычно MSSQL и соответственно T-SQL. Плюс IIS потому как под ним крутится приложение.

И не важно дотнетчик вы или нет, но если уж веб-программирование, то считают что вы должны знать базовые веб-технологии:

- HTML -- включая сюда и знание как работает HTTP/HTTPS, умения работы с браузерными инструмернами, Fiddler итп.
- CSS
- JavaScript
- JavaScript фреймворки -- и вот тут вообще большое поле, но обычно считают что хотя бы jQuery знаешь

В общем, то что описано выше -- это уже давно всё "commodity", т.е. зрелые технологии, которые давно всем известны и составляют основу, поэтому часто считают что веб-разработчик дотнетчик их просто знает.
Остальное -- это использование вами в работе различных сторонних библиотек и более других технологий -- это уже то что будет составлять ваш профессиональный опыт.

Answer (score 0):

Не зная вашего уровня программирования я бы посоветовал начать просто с языка. Знакомство с шарпами я начинал из Шилдта. Только когда уверенно чувствуешь в среде и знаешь семантику можно приступать к книге Адама Фримена.

Comment: Шилдт, кстати, один из худших авторов.

Comment: Я об этом узнал после прочтения)